# Android text alignment changed automatically

Tags: android, xml, layout

[image]
I am trying to create a layout it was working good yesterday but today I am opened the xml view all the text of controls is right aligned it happen with every screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
      >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_loginArea"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_loginArea"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/txt_box"
            android:hint="@string/usernamehint"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/txt_box"
            android:hint="@string/passwordhint"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="6dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/signin_button"
            android:text="@string/loginButtonText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_forgotpassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/forgotpassword" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_createAccount"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_facebook"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/facebook_button"
            android:text="@string/createaccount" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_createAccount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/create_account" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you please upload the code.

Comment: Can we see some xml code and screenshot?

Comment: these is no code only change in XML file every Button text shwing right alligned

Comment: How it is possible ? is this a magic code you wrote yesterday. Please post the code

Comment: strange but  it happen

Comment: Please check the screenshot

Comment: So Amit please try to run it on emulator or device and then check

Comment: Please run it on emulator/device and check if its ok in that.

Comment: @ user3924936 .... Can you pasete your code in pastebin or drop box  and provide a link here .... since it has selectors ... we can try on our end and see whats wrong here

Comment: @user3924936 I have faced same problem before 3 days. Just restart your eclipse and run once. And only in xml part you can see this type of issue otherwise when you run your app it will perfectly run.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `width` of `view` and make `view` `gravity="center"`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_createAccount"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_facebook"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/app_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="createaccount" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_createAccount"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@color/app_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="createaccount" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This question has no any answer.And its code for xml file is almost right. No need to change.

Comment: have updated the width of button and added gravity attribute in button view. this will make text always center.

Comment: I know this would be right. But OP's problem is different. I have faced same problem before 3 days.